# Possible to open 'Waze' from react app?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, waze

I want to have a google maps marker with two options:

- one for open google maps with the specific lng/lat - done.
- two - open "waze" application with the specific lng/lat - 
  how can i do that?

this is for the google maps:

```
<a href={"https://www.google.com/maps/?q=" + this.state.linkLat + "," +
    this.state.linkLng} target="_blank"><img alt="gmap" src={gmap}/></a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
<a 
  href={`https://waze.com/ul?ll=${this.state.linkLat},${this.state.linkLng}&navigate=yes`} 
  target="_blank">
    Open in Waze
</a>
```